# Yii2 console: How to disable color output in command via command line?

Tags: php, command-line, yii2, console-application

I like to have colors in output of my Yii2 console commands but in a special scenario I'm using it in a terminal that doesn't support colors and it looks all weird. Isn't there a command line option I can disable colors with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`--color`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controller#$color-detail) switch:

```
./yii my-command --color=0
```

Comment: Ahh, I was looking under yii\console\request, but it's in the controller of course.